# Setting MikTeX proxy from batch file

Tags: miktex, windows

I am trying to **automate** the installation of MikTeX on Windows 7 machines but fail when it comes to proxy definition. Manual definition using the GUI works well, but not the batch file based installation.

According to the [manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html) it should be possible to define the proxy by environment variables, but that did not work for me.

I have set the proxy with `set ALL_PROXY=my.proxy.name:3128` (`FTP_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` as well) but when trying to update the packages, I still get the well-known error message

```
mpm --admin --repository=ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ --verbose --update-db
mpm: Host not found
mpm: Data: get host by name failed in tcp_connect()
```

Did anybody succeed with providing proxy settings via batch-file?

Comment: What is "my.proxy,name". Do you have http:// at the begin? Did you try to add a trace?

Comment: "my.proxy.name" is the fully qualified domain name (no protocol scheme prefixes the host name) of my company-wide proxy server (no authentication required) within the company network. My system can resolve the host name and ping the proxy.

Comment: You could try if the `-proxy` option still exists. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1702/. If not I would suggest a bug report. Perhaps one need an environment variable to set the "use proxy".

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That appears to be a useful workaround. Perhaps I should really provide a bug report if no other SO users indicate that it is in fact a user-too-dumb-error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two workarounds.

First: use the `--proxy` option as in `mpm  --verbose --trace --update-db --proxy=my.proxy.name:8080 --repository=ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/putex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/` as Ulrike suggested. This workaround the disadvantage that the proxy parameter must be provided with every `mpm` command (no persistant setting as with the environment variable). Since the default repository appears to be non-existant, the repository needs to be specified as well.

Second: The settings can be made persistant by manipulating the registry.

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v ProxyAuthReq     /t REG_SZ /d f /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v ProxyHost        /t REG_SZ /d my.proxy.name /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v ProxyPort        /t REG_SZ /d 8080 /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v RepositoryType   /t REG_SZ /d remote /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v UseProxy         /t REG_SZ /d t /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\MPM /v RemoteRepository /t REG_SZ /d ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ /f
```